# Why a global function with recursion can directly be defined, but a local function can't

Tags: lua

a local function that directly define recursive functionality is wrong:

```lua
local fact = function (n)
  if n <= 1 then return 1
  else return n * fact(n - 1) end -- looking up global function
end
```

but for a global function, suck defination is ok:

```lua
function fact(n)
  if n <= 1 then return 1
  else return n * fact(n - 1) end -- correctly called itself
end
```

Why there has such difference? Global variables' scope is unbounded?(obvious not)

Comment: The examples are syntactically incorrect. There is no `end` to close the `if`.  Can you please provide a correct code to reproduce the problem you are talking about?

Comment: If the `end` was added, both would be semantically correct due to usage of `local function`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's actually incorrect; you can define local functions recursively:

```lua
local function fact(n)
   if n <= 1 then
      return 1
   else
      return n * fact(n -1)
   end
end
```

**However**, this doesn't work with anonymous functions:

```lua
local fact = function(n)
   -- ...
end
```

Because the right-hand-side of the assignment is evaluated before the left-hand-side. To make this work, you'd have to first declare the local:

```lua
local fact
fact = function(n)
   -- ...
end
```

But this problem doesn't affect the `local function name()` syntax as you described. As Egor pointed out, the problem with your code is that you don't close the `if` block with a corresponding `end`.

Comment: Why do you call `local f = function(...) end` "anonymous", but not `local function f(...) end`? The latter is literally just syntactic sugar for `local f; f = function(...) end`. Error messages will in both cases correctly call the function `local f`. It's just about the scope of the local declaration (before or after the function body).

Comment: @LDM All functions are technically "anonymous" in Lua, but from a syntax perspective, the first is a variable assignment with a function expression as the RHS while the second is a statement defining a named function (even though internally it gets turned into just another assignment).

Comment: That's why I wouldn't include the "anonymous" distinction in the first place, or at least put it in quotes as "anonymous". In the end the ref. manual explicitly states that this "named" func syntax is just sugar (both for local and global funcs) for func assignments; Lua always has to "guess" the name of a function from the context in the end (and will sometimes fail: The name is not an attribute of funcs in Lua).

Comment: @LMD Named vs. Anonymous ultimately always comes down to a syntactic distinction though. I'm not aware of any language that saves a functions name with the function for anything other than debugging. In that sense, all functions are ultimately anonymous.